# F# divide lists

Tags: list, f#, match

i'm learning a new programming language, which is F# and I'm struggling to solve a method. I need to divide a list of movies and books into to 2 lists. One where the movies are and another one where the books are listed in. I can't use functions that already exists in F#. I link some exemples what i have done until now. Thank you in advance

```
type Movie =
{ movieName: string
  duration: Nat
  fileSize: Nat }

type Book =
    { bookName: string
      pages: Nat }

type Activity =
    | Watch of Movie
    | Read of Book

let rec partitionActivities(activities: Activity list): (Book list * Movie list) = 
  match activities with
  | [] -> [],[]
  | x::_ -> match x with
    | Read Book -> [Book],[]
    | Watch Movie -> [],[Movie]
  | _::xs -> partitionActivities(xs)
```

What my inputs are :

```
partitionActivities [
                    Read { bookName = "A"; pages = 45N }
                    Watch { movieName = "B"; duration = 120N; fileSize = 50N }
                    Read { bookName = "C"; pages = 700N }
                    Watch { movieName = "D"; duration = 100N; fileSize = 1024N }
                    Watch { movieName = "E"; duration = 150N; fileSize = 9001N }
                    Read { bookName = "F"; pages = 700N }
```

What result should be :

```
[
                    { bookName = "A"; pages = 45N }
                    { bookName = "C"; pages = 700N }
                    { bookName = "F"; pages = 700N }
                ], [
                    { movieName = "B"; duration = 120N; fileSize = 50N }
                    { movieName = "D"; duration = 100N; fileSize = 1024N }
                    { movieName = "E"; duration = 150N; fileSize = 9001N }
                ]
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement `map` in F#? I would do this first as an exercise. It also seems your understanding of list pattern matching is wrong, see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/pattern-matching#cons-pattern

Comment: No i don´t. ok thanks i will check that.

Comment: You need to combine `x::_` and `_::xs` into one: `x::xs`

Comment: I also tried to combine them together but it still doesn´t work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right idea. Recurse with the tail of the list (`xs`), take the current `Activity`, determine if it involves a `Movie` or a `Book`, add it to the front of the corresponding list and return both lists:

```
let rec partitionActivities(activities: Activity list): (Book list * Movie list) = 
  match activities with
  | [] -> [], []
  | x::xs -> 
    let books, movies = partitionActivities(xs)
    match x with
    | Read book -> book::books, movies
    | Watch movie -> books, movie::movies
```

Comment: Thanks that helped me a lot !